# No instala la app Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

No me deja correr la aplicación de flutter que tengo, es una aplicación de 2020 y me ha tocado actualizarla.

Aquí se me queda enganchada la instalación de la app y no pasa de este punto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y se me queda con el nombre raro y sin imágen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se a que se debe esto pero me tiene loco, si necesitáis más información de algo me comentáis, gracias!!

Comment: Buenas, se recomienda añadir el código como texto, no como imagen. Te recomendaría crear un build de la aplicación, a ver si eso te arroja algo más de información

Comment: Se me queda igual, ahí enganchado y no pasa. Ya no se ni que hacer jaja.

Comment: ¿Supongo que habrás probado a realizar flutter clean, flutter cache repair y flutter pub get, no? Si no lo has probado, intenta usarlos, a ver qué tal. Está raro el problema. Si nada de eso lo soluciona, te recomendaría crear un proyecto nuevo en la última versión e ir pegando los archivos de tu carpeta lib a dicho proyecto así cómo las dependencias de tu pubspec. Te recomendaría rehacer cualquier configuración a mano, en lugar de copiarla.

Comment: Si lo de limpiar la cache lo probé. Ahora voy a probar eso que me has dicho de crear un proyecto nuevo para ver que tal, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que la versión de Flutter influye mucho en eso. Intenta crear un proyecto nuevo y añade los componentes de la aplicación vieja en la nueva. Ya Flutter agregó reglas como la del `Null Safety` que limita bastante el uso de proyectos viejos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Si te das cuenta, el .APK se construyó sin problemas, de hecho se detiene tratando de instalar el .APK en tu dispositivo:

```
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
```

Este es un problema conocido que incluso sucede en desarrollo android, en ocasiones no funciona realizando `flutter clean`, existen varias posibles soluciones, te enlisto 4 soluciones:

- Asegura que el cable de tu dispositivo funciona correctamente.
  En ocasiones puede fallar y esto impide que el .APK suba a tu dispositivo.
- Revoca y autoriza la depuración USB en tu computadora.
  Para autorizar nuevamente la depuración USB, ve a las opciones de desarrollador y deshabilita y habilita nuevamente la depuración USB, tienes que esperar unos segundos para que aparezca el diálogo que te permite autorizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Existe más de un perfil de usuario en tu teléfono.
  Ve a `Info. de la aplicación`, en la esquina superior derecha, selecciona "`Desisntala para todos los usuarios`".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Habilita desde la terminal la opción:

flutter build apk --no-shrink

Comment: No me funciona, ya no tengo ni idea de que hacer...